# Why isn't this reassigning working

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an arraylist called election(). Why isn't code this reassigning the name variable like it should.

```
private static void replaceName(String oldName, String newName){
    Candidate c;
    for(int i = 0;i<election().size();i++){
        c = election().get(i);
        if(c.name == oldName){
            election().get(0).name = newName;
            System.out.println(election().get(0).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "like it should" - please describe what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly comparing strings in your if statement. Instead of `c.name == oldName`, it should be `c.name.equals(oldName)`.

Also, you're assigning the new name to the wrong object.

Instead of `elections.get(0).name = newName`, it should be `c.name = newName` since c is a reference to the object stored in your ArrayList. Changes made to c will be reflected in your list. Your current code changes the name of the first candidate in your ArrayList, since you always call get() with 0 rather than i.

Comment: you are correct, but that still doesn't solve my issue

Comment: I updated my answer